# How create a new intent for each line of a list?

Tags: android, android-layout, listadapter

I have to make a list and call an intent different for each line. Can someone tell me what to write in code? The toast for now only appears to indicate that I'm calling that line.

```
public class Listview extends Activity {

    static ListView listView;


    static public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<Void, Person, Void> {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {
            // Prima di iniziare a inserire gli elementi svuotiamo l'adapter
            ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).clear();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground ( Void... params ) {

            // Qui dentro si possono mettere le operazioni che potrebbero
            // rallentare il caricamento della listview, come ad sempio il
            // caricamento da db degli oggetti



            Person[] people = { new Person( "Privacy", "", R.drawable.creep_1 ) };
            Person[] people1 = {new Person( "Visualizzazione", "", R.drawable.creep_2 )};
            Person[] people2=  { new Person( "Notifiche", "", R.drawable.creep_3 )};




            // riempimento casuale della lista delle persone
            Random r = new Random();

            for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
                // Pubblichiamo il progresso
                publishProgress( people);
                publishProgress( people1);
                publishProgress( people2);

            }

            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate ( Person... values ) {
            // Aggiungiamo il progresso pubblicato all'adapter
            ( ( ArrayAdapter<Person> ) listView.getAdapter() ).add( values[0] );
            super.onProgressUpdate( values );
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        listView = ( ListView ) findViewById( R.id.personListView );

        listView.setAdapter( new PersonAdapter( this, R.layout.row_item, new ArrayList<Person>() ) );

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Person p = (Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(
                        view.getContext(),
                        "Click sulla riga " + p.getFullName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show();
            }
        });

        new BackgroundWorker().execute();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement depending on the ListView's `position` and call the Activity you want.